# Boost Testing compilation error when installed with apt-get

Tags: c++, boost

I just installed Boost usig `sudo apt-get`. After that, I wrote the following code for testing one of my the functions I had declared in "first_n_follow.h"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<set>
#include<map>

#include "first_n_follow.h"
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

using namespace std;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test )
{
    set<char> sample = {'b','c','d'};
    map<char, set<char>> sample_map;
    sample_map['a'] = sample;
    BOOST_TEST(print_map(sample_map)==0);
}
```

Sadly, when I compile the above file `first_n_follow_test.cpp` using the following command:

```
g++ -o test.o first_n_follow_test.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccefJDJt.o: in function `my_test_invoker()':
first_n_follow_test.cpp:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t::set_checkpoint(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned long, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)'
```

followed by a long stack trace. Any ideas, as to what the problem might be?

Even if I replace the call to my code and write
`BOOST_TEST(0==0);`,
it shows the same error.
Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linkage of boost unit test framework library is missing

`g++ -o test.o first_n_follow_test.cpp -lboost_unit_test_framework`

Undefined reference errors usually means missing libraries or object files during linkage stage

Comment: It still shows the same error ```(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'```

Comment: @JeeveshJuneja replace your include with `#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>`

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I will study more about how all this linking etc. are happening. Would you mind suggesting a good reference? @user1056837